# Rails 4 - Do not scope if conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I want to create a scope with some conditions, with one returning not a specific scope. For now, this solution works:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(my_var) {
  scope = where('TRUE')
  if my_var.condition1?
     scope = scope.where({ :some_condition => :some_value })
  end
  if my_var.condition2?
     scope = scope.where({ :some_condition => :some_value })
  end
  scope 
}
```

Is there any other better solution to do this ?

Regards

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can safely omit `.` before where. I use the same solution in my code and it works well. Consider giving a less generic answer to get an in-depth answer.

Comment: Yeah, but my question was really about `my_var` and what kind of conditions you check on it? Depending on that you may handle this differently. As I said, I use conditions in scopes myself but would't say I consider this a very good practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Rails 4, you can simply use `all`:

```
scope :my_scope, ->(my_var) {
  if my_var.condition?
    where(some_condition: :some_value)
  else
    all
  end
}
```

؜ᅟᅠ             ⁠ㅤ

Comment: Does not `all` load all my AR objects ?

Comment: No - for example: `Model.custom_scope.all` returns results scoped by `custom_scope`.

Comment: Yes, but `Model.all.custom_scope` ? I have several scopes linked like this.

Comment: `Model.all.custom_scope` == `Model.custom_scope.all`. Since Rails 4 it's not a problem (because in Rails 4 `all` returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` instead of `Array`).