# Scope in Rails 5 for string match returning wrong sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a scope in Rails 5 that checks for the presence of a string value.

```
scope :category, ->(retro) {where retro: retro 
if retro.present? }
```

Now when this scope is called and the param from user input passed is null, the sql query generated is

```
'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE categories.retro IS NULL'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: I want the scope to run only when the parameter is not null

Comment: If it is `nil`, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: If the scope is null it should not called at all. I have similar scopes for integer matches which work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope :category, ->(retro) { where(retro: retro) if retro.present? }
```

Without the brackets, it's assumed that you want the `if` to be part of the SQL

Comment: Thank you, this worked.I had made a mistake with the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your `where` function call with parenthesis:

```
where(retro: retro) if retro.present?
```

The `if` was being applied to the parameter and not to the method call.

Comment: Are you sure it's this `scope` that's putting the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails4, you can use in below format. I guess same applies in Rails5

```
scope :category, ->(retro) {
  unless retro.blank?
    where(retro: retro)
  end
end
```

or

```
scope :category

def self.category(retro)
   unless retro.blank?
    where retro: retro
  end
end
```

Reference link

[Rails 4 - Do not scope if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241116/rails-4-do-not-scope-if-conditions)